# when I change mysql database I lose permissions

Tags: mysql, linux

I back up my MySql database by copying the entire var/lib/mysql folder to an external drive.  I do this whenever I've changed the database.  And every time, I get a message that I don't have permission for this.  So I have to go back and reset them.

I must have something set up wrong, but I don't know what.  Can anyone offer advice or a clue?

I'm running under Ubuntu 14.04 MySql 5.5.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/15644

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/137424/moving-mysql-datadir

Comment: Hi Kumar, the link provided me a clue, but it did seem as if all my files were set for rwx.  A friend suggests I reset the permissions to 777, so I'll try that.  Thanks for setting me on the right track.

Comment: Well, setting it to 777 did not change anything.  I'm still losing permissions on any table I make a change to.  I've read both links again, and don't see an answer for me.  It must be something I don't understand about which user owns what.  I thought using chmod for the entire var/lib/mysql folder would settle it, but apparently not.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The question is old, but since the only answer addresses something different, I'll take a stab at it in case somebody else finds this through a search. The behavior you are observing is intentional.

There are two separate levels of permissions involved. There are the actual files on the file system, which is what you are trying to deal with.

And then there are MySQL's own permissions, which are completely separate. That's what Ataboy Josef is referring to.

The problem here is that MySQL really, really does not want you to deal with the files, ever. The same is true for most other databases, too. Don't do it with Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server etc. (SQLite tends to be an exception here), all for the same reason: it's not safe.

What you are trying to do is the exact thing MySQL is trying to discourage, because it can lead to inconsistent databases or corruption. So MySQL will reset the Linux permissions every chance it gets.

You have two ways to deal with this.

- Use MySQL's own backup mechanism. This is the recommended approach in 99% of all cases.
- Back up the /var/lib/mysql directory as you are attempting to do. This will require understanding the implications, and usually several preparation steps first to deal with the consequences.

### To make a backup the recommended way:

You use the mysqldump utility. It will generate a file with SQL code that you can later replay to restore your database. There are plenty of resources online on how to do that, for instance this: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqldump/ A simple backup command you might use is this (test this as it may not fit for your specific situation):

```
mysqldump --all-databases >backup.sql
```

Depending on your situation, you may also need to supply user names and passwords for the backup, specify the database host name (yes, mysqldump can back up across the network if your database allows it), or various other attributes.

### To back up the mysql files (rarely the right way to do it):

If you do want to back up /var/lib/mysql directly, here is how it can be done:

First, decide about the level of the backup. You can get a fully safe backup, you can get what's called a crash-consistent backup (meaning that, when restored, the backup will look as if MySQL had crashed, and MySQL can then try to recover from that), or you can make what I'd call a naive backup (which may end up completely corrupt).

#### To make a naive backup (dangerous)

You do exactly what you proposed in your question. The problem is that you may get corruption (in the backup, the original DB will be fine) that you may not even notice until months later. This happens because if MySQL is active, either because something is actually being written to it, or because MySQL is doing some internal housekeeping, you may be backing up part of the database before the change, and part after the chance.

#### To make a crash-consistent backup (typically, but not always, somewhat safe)

An improvement to doing that is what's called a crash-consistent backup. This may still contain half-written transactions, but at least all the transactions come from one point in time.

To make such a crash-consistent backup, you need to take a file-level snapshot, using whatever tools your file system offers, for instance LVM snapshots. Explaining the details would be off topic here, so I'll just point you to one link: https://www.theurbanpenguin.com/maning-lvm-snapshots/ If that link goes away, simply search for LVM Snapshot, and you will find dozens more.

Then back up the snapshot, instead of backing up the original /var/lib/mysql directory.

Finally, don't forget to delete the snapshot (otherwise, you will lose disk space as well as performance - snapshots are not free!)

This snapshot is taken at one point in time, so you are not backing up while activity is still happening, but you may still take the snapshot after data has been half-way written. If you are lucky, the database is quiet when the snapshot is taken, and you may get a backup without a problem. If you are unlucky, MySQL will at least know to discard the half-written last transactions.

#### To make a safe backup (mostly safe but disruptive)

If you actually want to back up /var/lib/mysql and avoid all risk of corruption, you have to prevent MySQL from touching the databases at all during the backup. To do that, you have to stop the mysqld service, make the backup, and then restart the service.

Obviously, that means that the mysqld server will be down, possibly for an extended period. in a production environment that's rarely acceptable.

You can reduce the downtime by combining this with the filesystem snapshot approach suggested earlier.

#### Permissions

With all of this, I did not address your original question about permissions. If you really want, you can change them the way you proposed, right before every backup. But since generally, you only want to take this approach if you really know what you are doing, the better approach is to do this as root, where the permissions become a non-issue.

### Third-party backup programs

One other interesting question in this context is what third-party backup programs will do to back up your MySQL database. They generally take one of the three approaches outlined above.

Some low-end applications will take the naive approach. That type of backup is obviously not very reliable. That's why those backups are low-end! If you can't find anything in the documentation, that often means that you'll get this type of backup.

Better applications use a snapshot mechanism, and will get you a crash-consistent backup.

And finally, good backup programs (most of them are not free) have plugins for databases (and often various other applications), or let you write your own scripts. Those will generally use either mysqldump, or have their own similar tool built in.

Comment: This is a very useful essay, as it explains in much more depth what is going on.  I long ago switched to mysql dump, which I am deeply unimpressed with.  It is basically serializing the entire mysql system, and then reloading everything.  It seems okay for my small files, but I wonder how well it does if the tables are large.  I think at some point I have to go to a third party system, which is probably better than my homegrown efforts, but it's not necessary quite yet.

Comment: @BettyMock Thank you for the compliment, glad it still helped after such a long time. Fundamentally, if you really need that kind of backup, mysql may not be the proper tool for the job. While mysql is perfectly good for production databases, it isn't the right tool for *humongous* databases or when you need to-the-millisecond point-in-time restores. For those, you probably need paid databases that back up the main database+log files. That said, mysqldump has one definite advantage: a restore will also fix most file-level corruption, because it builds a *new* database.

Answer (score 0):

If you have never set a root password for MySQL, the server does not require a password at all for connecting as root. However, this is insecure. For instructions on assigning passwords, here is, “[Securing the Initial MySQL Accounts](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/default-privileges.html)”.

If you know the root password, but want to change it, see “[SET PASSWORD Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set-password.html)”.

If you set a root password previously, but have forgotten it, you can set a new password. The following sections provide instructions for Windows systems, as well as generic instructions that apply to any system.

On Windows, use the following procedure to reset the password for all MySQL root accounts:

Log on to your system as Administrator.

Stop the MySQL server if it is running. For a server that is running as a Windows service, go to the Services manager: From the Start menu, select Control Panel, then Administrative Tools, then Services. Find the MySQL service in the list and stop it.

If your server is not running as a service, you may need to use the Task Manager to force it to stop.

Create a text file containing the following statements. Replace the password with the password that you want to use.

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Write the UPDATE and FLUSH statements each on a single line. The UPDATE statement resets the password for all root accounts, and the FLUSH statement tells the server to reload the grant tables into memory so that it notices the password change.

Save the file. For this example, the file will be named C:\mysql-init.txt.

Open a console window to get to the command prompt: From the Start menu, select Run, then enter cmd as the command to be run.

Start the MySQL server with the special --init-file option (notice that the backslash in the option value is doubled):

```
C:\> C:\mysql\bin\mysqld --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt
If you installed MySQL to a location other than C:\mysql
```

, adjust the command accordingly.

The server executes the contents of the file named by the --init-file option at startup, changing each root account password.

You can also add the --console option to the command if you want server output to appear in the console window rather than in a log file.

If you installed MySQL using the MySQL Installation Wizard, you may need to specify a --defaults-file option:

```
C:\> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld.exe"
         --defaults-file="C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.1\\my.ini"
         --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt
```

The appropriate --defaults-file setting can be found using the Services Manager: From the Start menu, select Control Panel, then Administrative Tools, then Services. Find the MySQL service in the list, right-click it, and choose the Properties option. The Path to executable field contains the --defaults-file setting.

After the server has started successfully, delete C:\mysql-init.txt.

You should now be able to connect to the MySQL server as root using the new password. Stop the MySQL server, then restart it in normal mode again. If you run the server as a service, start it from the Windows Services window. If you start the server manually, use whatever command you normally use.